# Custom ordered set give "invalid operator<" of find(...)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, set

Have a issue when I'm trying to find element in a custom ordered set.

```
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree
Line: 1746

Expression: invalid operator<
```

I need a set of strings where the elements are ordered accordingly my needs.

Comparator object:

```
struct OrderComparator {
public:
    static map<string,int> valueOrder;

    bool operator()( const string lhs, const string rhs ) {
        map<string,int>::iterator resultLhs,resultRhs;
        resultLhs = valueOrder.find(lhs);
        resultRhs = valueOrder.find(rhs);
        if (resultLhs == valueOrder.end() || resultRhs == valueOrder.end())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            bool result = resultLhs->second <= resultRhs->second;
            return result;
        }
    }

    static map<string,int> create_map()
    {
        map<string,int> m;
        m["A"] = 1; 
        m["B"] = 2;
        m["C"] = 3;
        m["D"] = 4;
        return m;
    }
};
```

---

Comparator is working fine!

But when I'm trying to search in the set getting mentioned error.

```
typedef set<string, OrderComparator> TREESET_CMP;
...
TREESET_CMP::iterator it = myTree.find(obj); <-fails
...
```

Will be glad if some one can tell me why this is happening and how to fix it.

---

Full working Mini Example:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

struct OrderComparator {
public:
    static map<string,int> valueOrder;

    bool operator()( const string lhs, const string rhs ) {
        map<string,int>::iterator resultLhs,resultRhs;
        resultLhs = valueOrder.find(lhs);
        resultRhs = valueOrder.find(rhs);
        if (resultLhs == valueOrder.end() || resultRhs == valueOrder.end())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            bool result = resultLhs->second <= resultRhs->second;
            return result;
        }
    }

    static map<string,int> create_map()
    {
        map<string,int> m;
        m["A"] = 1; 
        m["B"] = 2;
        m["C"] = 3;
        m["D"] = 4;
        return m;
    }
};
map<string,int> OrderComparator::valueOrder = OrderComparator::create_map();

typedef set<string, OrderComparator> TREESET_CMP;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TREESET_CMP myTree;
    myTree.insert("B");
    myTree.insert("C");
    myTree.insert("A");

    TREESET_CMP::const_iterator it = myTree.find("A");
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: *"Comparator is working fine!"*.. How do you know this? As-written, if `create_map()` is not called (and why that isn't in a constructor of this object and held as a member I'm still not understanding) *all* elements are guaranteed to return `false`, thereby breaking the strict order requirement of a map-comparator.

Comment: obj is a string. "A" or "X".

Comment: @WhozCraig I do not think that always returning false would break strict order requirement. Always returning true would.

Comment: @SairuS can you make minimum compilable example showing your issue?

Comment: "Comparator is working fine!"... because I tested. "create_map()" - is called. I agree that we can find optimize the cod. but this is not the case :)

Comment: @Slava, `cmp(x, y)` implies `!cmp(y, x)`, always returning false breaks the antisymetric requirement

Comment: @SairuS I am not sure what cases you tested, but your comparator is not correct.

Comment: @JonathanWakely cmp(x,y) implies !cmp(y,x ) only if x and y are different, always false from cmp() would mean all elements are equal, how that breaks anything?

Comment: OK, I will prepare MINIMUM example and will repost it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Strictly speaking, if cmp(x,y) always returns false, it is still antisymmetric. Antisymmetry says cmp(x,y)==true => cmp(y,x)==false, not cmp(x,y)==logical-not(cmp(y,x))

Comment: Ah yes, good point, thanks. Logic fail. The OP's comparison function does fail the anti-symmetry requirement though.

Comment: @Slava You're correct. It would ultimately result in a map where all keys are equal. Therefore you would never have more than **one** element mapped no matter what key was used. If that isn't "broken", so be it. [See it live](http://ideone.com/BPG7pu). Maps determine key "sameness" by checking ultimately for !(K1<K2 || K2<K1), though that is implementation defined (methinks) I've never seen it done any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator can be this:

```
bool operator()( const string &lhs, const string &rhs ) {
    map<string,int>::iterator resultLhs,resultRhs;
    resultLhs = valueOrder.find(lhs);
    resultRhs = valueOrder.find(rhs);
    if (resultLhs == valueOrder.end()) return false;
    if (resultRhs == valueOrder.end()) return true;

    return resultLhs->second < resultRhs->second;
}
```

You can replace 2 lines to:

```
if (resultRhs == valueOrder.end()) return false;
if (resultLhs == valueOrder.end()) return true;
```

If you want strings that do not exist in your map to be sorted before that do.

Comment: @SairuS you're welcome. I hope you read Jonathan's answer and understood why it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison doesn't define a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)

A strict weak ordering must have these invariants (quoted from the link above)

- **Irreflexivity**     f(x, x) must be false.
- **Antisymmetry**  f(x, y) implies !f(y, x)
- **Transitivity**  f(x, y) and f(y, z) imply f(x, z).
- **Transitivity of equivalence**    Equivalence (as defined above) is transitive: if x is equivalent to y and y is equivalent to z, then x is equivalent to z. (This implies that equivalence does in fact satisfy the mathematical definition of an equivalence relation.)

Yours fails at least Irreflexivity (comparing an object to itself must be false) and Antisymmetry (if x is less-than y, then y is not less-than x)

Basically, `<=` is not a valid ordering, because `x <= x` returns true, which means you can never find an element in the set. To find an element the set looks for an element with the property `!cmp(key, element) && !cmp(element, key)` but that can never work for your ordering.

The simplest fix might be to change `<=` to `<`, but there could be other problems.

Comment: +1 There are definite "other" problems. If a key (or worse, *both*) is NOT in the internal map, it all-but-guarantees breaking anti-symmetry,  which obviously isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your comparison method to be `const` and to use const references for the arguements. The first fix is to ensure that you can call your method with constant versions of your `OrderComarator` the second fix is to avoid copying.

```
bool operator()( const string& lhs, const string& rhs ) const {
```