# What my customized compare does not work?

Tags: c++

I wrote a compare operator as below:

```
struct GreaterThan
{
    bool operator() (string a, string b)
    {

        if (a.length() == 1 && a[0] == b[0]) //LINE1
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (b.length() == 1 && b[0] == a[0]) //LINE2
        {
            return true;
        }

        return a.compare(b) == 1 ? true : false;
   }
};

vector<string> v{"2", "20", "5", "7"};
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), GreaterThan());
```

The purpose of LINE1 and LINE2 is to make "2" ahead of "20" when sorting.
But it causes runtime error. The error is "invalid operator<" on visual studio.

Comment: what would you do if "20" and "200" are present? It seems like you should look at the length of the string instead

Comment: also, your error is probably more that what you gave us. Can you add a bit more of compiler output?

Comment: You need to define a [*strict weak ordering*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). You have `"2" > "2"`, which makes your ordering invalid.

Comment: None of this generates a runtime error on `operator <`. The sorting may produce odd, unexpected, erroneous or all of the above results but not a runtime error.

Comment: Ah, the old `return (condition)  ? true : false`. Amateur mistake. It should be: `if (condition) { return condition == true ? (true && !false)  : !true; } else { return !condition && false; }` Otherwise how would anyone know what you're returning?

Comment: @haavee It does on MSVC in Debug builds. They have some checks to detect invalid comparators.

Comment: So, what does an invalid comparator mean then? How does it check?

Comment: Ah, I already found it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15254479/26083 lists how the compiler checks and thus explains why your comparator fails.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `std::string::compare` doesn't have to be `1` when `a` is "greater than" `b`. It just has to be greater than `0`.

Instead of

```
return a.compare(b) == 1 ? true : false;
```

I think you need:

```
return (a.compare(b) < 0);
```